# ANOVA over time but not repeated measures

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, experiment-design, multilevel-analysis

I have an experiment that was incorrectly designed. I'm trying to see what analysis I should provide, but I'm a little confused.

A brief description of the experiment:

Rats were given one of four drugs: control, A, D or S. The experiment lasted four months. At the end of each month, half of the rats in each drug group were killed and had their bone density measured. At the end of the fourth month the final batch of rats is killed and all the participants in the experiment are no longer alive.

To me this is like a repeated measures design, but without any repeated measures. I've been considering the model:

$y_{itk} = \tau_i + \beta_t + (\tau * \beta)_{it} + e_{itk}$

where $\tau$ is the treatment effect, $\beta$ is the time effect, $\tau * \beta$ is the treatment by time interaction, and $e$ is unexplained variance. I can make the standard assumption and say the $e$'s are normally distributed, but they are clearly not iid. The responses are correlated within treatment and also correlated within a given time period.

I've considered fitting the above model, but with a completely unspecified covariance matrix. Is this appropriate? Is there a better way (is there any way??) to analyze this data?

Comment: This sounds like a standard (but unbalanced) two-way anova.

Comment: I thought two-way anova assumes the groups are independent from one another?

Comment: Let me be more specific. In two way anova you assume $e_{itk} \sim N(0, \sigma^2$). We cannot assume this here because of the correlation within treatment and correlation within time period.

Comment: Why can't u assume it? AFAIK you can assume anything - As long as you check it afterwards. Do the model and then look at the behaviour of the residuals. If they are fine, then they are fine. If not, then back to the drawing board.

Comment: I don't understand why there are any correlations or dependencies.

Comment: Is it not correct to expect (or explicitly include in my model) that a a rat who received drug A then waited for 3 months will correlated with a rat that received drug A then waited 4 months? Am I making too much of this?

Comment: That correlation is taken on account by the model. $\beta$ for 3 months can be similar to $\beta$ for 4 months, and the same can be said about interaction, but that doesn't mean residuals are correlated.